# ASP.NET 4.0 - Hosting a ReportViewer control inside a Web Part control

Tags: web-parts, reportviewer, asp.net-4.0

I have a series of reports designed in Reporting Services that I'd like to make available through a single ASP.NET web page. I plan to make the reports available via the ReportViewer control. Unfortunately we don't have SharePoint available and my company isn't looking to buy it - so I'm stuck (I believe) with this method.

Is it possible to host a ReportViewer control inside a Web Part control? First off the ReportViewer control displays my reports perfectly on the page. But once I wrap them in the WebPartZone control I get the following error:

```
The DataSourceID of the ReportDataSource 'DataSet1' of the ReportViewer 'ReportViewer1' must be the ID of a control of type IDataSource. A control with ID 'ObjectDataSource1' could not be found.
```

Here is an example web part / report declaration:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Font-Names="Verdana" 
                    Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
                    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
                    <LocalReport ReportPath="Report2.rdlc">
                        <DataSources>
                            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
                        </DataSources>
                    </LocalReport>
                </rsweb:ReportViewer>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    SelectMethod="GetProducts" TypeName="Merchant"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

The reason I'm using Web Parts is to make a dashboard style page.

What can I do to make the datasource available?
Or perhaps there is a better / easier way to generate a dashboard style layout in ASP.NET for reporting services reports.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer or find a response to this? I have a similar question.